# Solving a Differential Equations Initial Value Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, initial-value-problems

[Here's a link to the question. I'm trying to reduce the order of the differential equation by letting u = y' and u' = y'' but I've only gotten stuck later in the process when trying to find a fundamental matrix. Also, I should add that in my class we haven't learned Abel's Theorem or Variation of Parameters. Thank you for any help!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsjhm.png)

Comment: When I pose a question, I try to supply at least minimal detail to show that I have somewhat tried to go about solving the problem on my own..Do you have anything you can show us that will help us guide you through the question? Rather than just throwing a homework problem to us

Comment: Since you know one solution, you need to use reduction of order. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ReductionofOrder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in the question.  The first equation should be set equal to $0$.  You are given one solution to the homogeneous equation.  Use reduction of order to find a second solution.  Then the homogeneous (or complementary) solution will be
$y_h = c_1e^{-x^2/2} + c_2f(x).$

Now you need a nonhomogeneous (or particular) solution, $y_p$.  You don't need variation of parameters or Abel's theorem here since they gave you a strong hint.  $y_p = x^2$ doesn't quite work, but I bet you can massage it a little.  Then the final answer is $y=y_h+y_p.$